# Remove leading Zero in CSV file using Unix sed command

Tags: bash, csv, unix, sed

My csv file is:

```
1234,0045,0045,0345,300
1235,0046,0446,2345,301
1236,0047,0447,0350,302
```

I need the result like this:

```
1234,45,45,345,300
1235,46,446,2345,301
1236,47,447,350,302
```

I want to accomplish this task using Unix SED command. Any other alternative method is also appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
$ sed 's/^0*\([^,]\)/\1/;s/,0*\([^,]\)/,\1/g' yourfile.csv
1234,45,45,345,300
1235,46,446,2345,301
1236,47,447,350,302
```